# finding $\mathcal{F}$ or classes in $\mathcal{F}$

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics, gr.group-theory

Let $\mathcal{F}$ be the set of functions (sequences, if you like) $f:\mathbb{Z}_{\geq0}\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}$ such that

(a) $f(0)$ is odd, and

(b) $2^{n+1}\,\vert\,(\Delta^nf)(x)$ for all $n\geq1$ and all $x\in\mathbb{Z}_{\geq0}$. Here
$$(\Delta f)(x):=(Sf)(x)-f(x):=f(x+1)-f(x).$$

**Examples.** The Fibonacci sequence $F(x)=F_x\not\in\mathcal{F}$ but it is a cute exercise $F(6x+1)\in\mathcal{F}$. The polynomial $f(x)=(2x+1)^2\in\mathcal{F}$.

For the motivation on this subject and some sequences $f$ belonging to $\mathcal{F}$, [see this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0601339v2.pdf).

> **Questions.**
>
> (1) Which class/family of polynomials are in $\mathcal{F}$?
>
> (2) Which family of familiar or combinatorial sequences are in $\mathcal{F}$?
>
> (3) Anything else?

Your suggested class doesn't have to be the most general.
We will just keep a catalogue here.

Answer (score 3):

I think I have an answer for (1).

Let $P(x)=\sum_k\alpha_kx^k$ be a polynomial. Then, we can express $P$ in the binomial basis $\{\binom{x}m\}_m$ in the manner
$$P(x)=\sum_m\beta_m\binom{x}m.$$
Now, $P(x)$ is integer-valued iff each $\beta_m\in\mathbb{Z}$. The criterion (1) and (2) enforce the conditions: 
$$\text{$\beta_0$ is odd} \qquad \text{and} \qquad 2^{m+1}\,\vert\, \beta_m.$$
To complete the argument, it suffices to observe that $\beta_m=(\Delta^mP)(0)$ and for Condition (b) use 
$$\Delta\binom{x}m=\binom{x}{m-1}.$$
Therefore, we know exactly which polynomials belong to $\mathcal{F}$. Let's denote this collection by $\mathcal{F}_P\subset\mathcal{F}$.